# Problem installing the RePsychLing package

Tags: r

I'm trying to install the `RePsychLing` package using RStudio and I'm getting the same error over and over again.

The package must be downloaded from this [website](https://github.com/dmbates/RePsychLing) using `devtools`, which I have already installed. The code that I would need to write in RStudio is `devtools::install_github("dmbates/RePsychLing")`

And this is the error I get (both from RStudio and from R itself):

```
    Downloading GitHub repo dmbates/RePsychLing@master
tar: Failed to set default locale
tar: Failed to set default locale
   During startup - Warning messages:
   1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
   2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
   3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
   4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C" 
<U+221A>  checking for file '/private/var/folders/2d/t2899bk50r1gjbjvgqyj63nh0000gp/T/RtmpJMVAfL/remotes749271204207/dmbates-RePsychLing-392adf1/DESCRIPTION'
-  preparing 'RePsychLing':
<U+221A>  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'RePsychLing_0.0.4.tar.gz' (941ms)

Error: (converted from warning) Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
Execution halted
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package '/var/folders/2d/t2899bk50r1gjbjvgqyj63nh0000gp/T//RtmpJMVAfL/file749239303256/RePsychLing_0.0.4.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

Does anyone know what it means or what I would have to do in order to download the package?

Comment: are you sure you need it?  The latest release of `lme4` (1.1-19) has the `rePCA` function included ... what else is in `rePsychLing`?

Comment: It's a package that includes data sets, among others. I need to install it for a Psychology course I'm taking.

Comment: what is the value of `options("warn")`?  Did you somehow set it to 2, which would convert warnings to errors? Does `options(warn=0)` (resetting to default) help?

Comment: @BenBolker I have checked and the value is already set to 0.

Comment: I think the answer to this issue gives a clue: https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/272

Comment: search https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/blob/master/README.md for `R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS=true`